# In jquery, how can I put the uploaded files in the php $_FILES array without changing page?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

My question is all in the title. 
I am trying to make a multiple file upload form, and want to have an Upload button for every file whenever I click "Add another file".

So I don't wanna change page because those uploaded files are combined with text fields as well.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, I am looking into this. Regards